# Prove that $x^3$ is strictly increasing on the real numbers using inequality properties

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

I'm attempting to prove that $x^3$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$, but I'm encountering two issues. Firstly, I'm uncertain about the precise definition of a strictly increasing function.

**Definition:** $f$ is said to be a strictly function on the interval $I$ if, and only if,

$$\forall x_1,x_2\in I, x_1<x_2\rightarrow f(x_1)<f(x_2).$$

What is the specific form of argument used in this definition? Why? (I think b is correct)

a. $p \wedge (q\rightarrow r)$

b. $(p \wedge q)\rightarrow r$

The second issue I face is determining how to prove the following statement using properties of inequalities.

$$\forall a,b\in\mathbb{R},a>b\rightarrow a^3>b^3$$

Comment: your definition of strictly increasing functions is correct.

Comment: Compare https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1560209/42969

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, b is correct. We suppose two things, and they together imply a conclusion. For the second point notice that $$ a^3>b^3 \iff a^3-b^3>0 \iff (a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)>0$$
But we know that $(a-b)>0$ and $(a^2+ab+b^2) \geq (a+\frac{1}{2}b)^2 \geq 0$, and $a^2+ab+b^2>0$ is in fact strict because we know that the first inequality is an equality only if $b=0$ and the second is an equality only if $2a=-b \implies a=0$ which is impossible.

Comment: what about case of $a = -1$ and $b = 0$